# Estou em um projeto em react native, preciso mostrar os dados vindo do banco em uma tabela no front, consigo construir uma tabela com react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, mobile, table, expo

Preciso de uma informação, consigo construir uma tabela de dados com react native? Qual recomendação para a construção? Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo mobile, com java script, react native, utilizando o expo. Preciso listar os dados vindo do banco em uma tabela, qual a melhor solução no meu caso? O que devo utilizar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o pacote expo-sqlite

https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/sqlite/